# How to convert a JSON string to PSObject?

Tags: c#, json, psobject

I want to write a PowerShell function in C#. During the process I receive a string with JSON content. 
My sample json content is:

```
string json = "{'TestNr':{'Name':'CSHARP', 'Description':'Test Descriptiopn'}}"
```

This string should be converted to a PSObject just like `ConvertFrom-Json` would do.

I was trying to create an object with below lines. It works but it would require a lot of manual scripting especially if the JSON string becomes longer.

```
PSObject obj = new PSObject();
obj.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Head", "Children"));
```

I tried also the below line:

```
obj = (PSObject)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PSObject)).ConvertFromString(json);
```

For this I get however the **error** (I run the function in PowerShell 7):

> TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String.

Comment: `var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);` would convert it to a JObject. I would not try to bring powershell into C# and start looking into method and processes that C# gives you to "serialize" and "deserialize" the json object/string

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: @bob, I believe I eventually used some version of Jawad's first options. It is however suboptimal as the Json objects were dynamic so the classes didn't match and the deserialization failed occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can parse the string in C# that would be the easiest to go with.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public TestNRClass TestNR { get; set; }
}

public class TestNRClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

// In the main,
string json = @"{""TestNr"":{""Name"":""CSHARP"", ""Description"":""Test Descriptiopn""}}";

MyClass jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
Console.WriteLine(jobj.TestNR.Name);
```

This is with the strong typed class object. This is what you should be using in C#.

Other way is to get an object

```
string json = @"{""TestNr"":{""Name"":""CSHARP"", ""Description"":""Test Descriptiopn""}}";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(obj["TestNr"]["Name"].ToString());

// You can also add more keyValuePair
obj["NewVariable"] = "stest";
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString()); // Shows the new item as well.
```